# Jasper Reports in JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jasper-reports

How to display jasper reports in JSP page? I am using iReport1.3.3 tool to create
reports. I am struggling to display jasper report in JSP page.

Is it possible to pass ArrayList to jasper reports?

I need to display the report in PDF and EXcel format.

Comment: Doing this in a JSP sounds like a very bad idea. Why don't you do this in a servlet?

Comment: @Maurice.. this is my requirement..I am using struts framework, once 
     action get success i am forwarding it to xx.jsp page.in that
     page i am creating hyperlink on some data. if i click that
     hyperlink it should invoke the jasper reports template and it
     shown as PDF format. 
     Please help me i am struggling for long week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written an struts (1.1) application that renders PDFs and CSVs. I would do this in an action handler:

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        // generate the PDF
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

UPDATE: feeding collections to JasperReports

```
package reports;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Arrays;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRField;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException;

public class CollectionDataSource implements JRDataSource {
    private Iterator iterator = null;
    private Object current = null;

    public CollectionDataSource(Collection col) {
        if (col != null) {
            iterator = col.iterator();
        }
    }

    public CollectionDataSource(Object array[]) {
        this(Arrays.asList(array == null ? new Object[0] : array));
    }

    public boolean next() throws JRException {
        if (iterator == null || !iterator.hasNext()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            current = iterator.next();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Object getFieldValue(JRField field) throws JRException {
        if ("this".equals(field.getName())) {
            return current;
        } else if (current == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Class<?> clazz = current.getClass();
            char chars[] = field.getName().toCharArray();
            chars[0] = Character.toUpperCase(chars[0]);
            String name = new String(chars);
            Method method = null;
            try {
                method = clazz.getMethod("get" + name);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                if (field.getValueClass() == Boolean.class) {
                    try {
                        method = clazz.getMethod("is" + name);
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e1) {
                    }
                }
            }
            if (method == null) {
                throw new JRException("No getter for field " + name);
            }
            try {
                return method.invoke(current);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new JRException("Exception in getter of " + name, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Maurice.. is it like by clicking hyperlink in jsp page, will render pdf or excel format reports

Comment: and also if you don't mind can you send me some complete sample codes 
       for this. my email id is :  i2iniru@gmail.com 
       or i2inirupan@gmail.com

Comment: is it possible to pass ArrayList to xyz.jasper(xyz is filename)
 template and fill it to pdf or excel format ?

Comment: @Maurice.. if you don't mind can you send me some sample code for pdf and csv format generation using servlets for jasper reports..

Comment: I don't have any: I've only used jasper reports in desktop apps.

Comment: Concerning the ArrayList question, I have added the code of a CollectionDataSource that I have written (a while ago).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a DefaultJasperViewer.jsp, it is mentioned on http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=35938

I think it would be nicer to write a taglib. Take a look here: http://seamframework.org/Community/JasperReportsSeam
This is related to JSF and Seam, but might give some inspiration.